# simple way to check 2 variables at once for null or empty

Tags: powershell, null

Seeking a simple way (ideally a single line of code) to check if either of 2 variables is empty something like below, however, this doesn't work...

```
if ([string]::isnullorempty(var1,var2)) {"empty"} else {"not empty"}
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just use ```if( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($var1) -or [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($var2) ) ...```?

Comment: `if ('' -in [String[]]($var1, $var2)) { 'IsNullOrEmpty' }`

Comment: Thank you for your comments and advise - these both work well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The not operator will convert a string to a boolean.  Try this:

```
if (!$var1 -or !$var2) {"empty"} else {"not empty"}
```

I think that !$var1 will return $true if $var1 is null or empty.

Comment: To match the exact semantics of the original you probably need ```if (!([string]$var1) -or !([string]$var2)) {"empty"} else {"not empty"}``` because in an extreme edge case ```$var1``` could be the boolean value ```$false``` and ```!$false``` -> ```$true``` but ```!([string]$false)``` -> ```$false```. Although I'm guessing it's unlikely it'll be an actual problem in the OP's context :-)...